# Different Entity for each User?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently working with Entity Framework and currently I am unable to understand how to do this:
I have a class called question, like this:

```
public class Question
{
 public int QuestionID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

each user looks like this:

```
public class User
{
 public int UserID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

each User can (and will) answer a unknown Number of Questions, but how can I seperate the answers for each user? Currently, EF seems to include a Foreign Key into the Queystion Table, which is not really what I want.
Maybe I lack the Understand and / or terminology for this problem, so I would appreciate a link to good advice ;)

Comment: So are the answers free form, multiple choice, or a mixture? e.g. Is there a correct answer for a question?

Comment: @Romoku The answer will be stored in the "Value" portion of a Question. Description etc. is stored in the Question class, but I omitted them here for brevity.

Comment: Well there is a many-to-many relationship between questions and users, so storing the answer inside a question won't work. Try making a class to store the answer like `public class UserQuestionAnswer { public int QuestionID { get; set; } public int UserID { get; set; } public int? Value { get; set; } }` and remove the collection from `User`.

Comment: Ah, now I understand you, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your have a many-to-many relationship between `Question` and `User`.

Create a new class to express this relationship and hold the user selection and remove the `Questions` property from the `User`.

```
public class UserQuestionAnswer
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int? Value { get; set; }
}
```

For entity framework specific setup see: [Defining many to many relation in code first entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327992/defining-many-to-many-relation-in-code-first-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a class QuestionUser that will have the user and the question, as the name says. Then you can select the question by users or see what questions were made to each user, etc. 
With this you avoid an explicit connection between the two classes.

EDIT:

then you have question with the correct answer:

```
public class Question
{
 public int QuestionID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public int? Value { get; set; }
 public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

the user:

```
public class User
{
 public int UserID { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

the userQuestion class that make the link and have the user answer:

```
public class UserQuestion
{
 public User User { get; set; }
 public Question Question { get; set; }
 public string userAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

with this model you gonna have what you want I think.

Comment: As I understand that, theere would be still only one row for the Questions and thus I would be unable to store the answers for each user?

Comment: well you could find those questions like: `questions in questionuser where user.id = userX.id` (this is just an pseudo code). and when an user answer a question you could save in questionUser table, the question and the user so you will have an historycal of it.